# AttributeError: module 'click.utils' has no attribute '_expand_args', when i'm tring to install en_core_web_sm

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy, spacy-3

I am trying to install "en_core_web_sm",
the commands i ran is:

1. pip install spacy ( which ran perfectly and got installed)
2. python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm ( here i'm getting error "AttributeError: module 'click.utils' has no attribute '_expand_args'" )

[image]

Please help to me resolve this problem.

#CODE

import nl_core_news_sm

## Load pre-trained Dutch language model

nlp = nl_core_news_sm.load()

## File Extension. set as 'pdf' or as 'doc(x)'

extension = 'pdf'

def create_tokenized_texts_list(extension):
'''Create two lists, one with the names of the candidate and one with the tokenized
resume texts extracted from either a .pdf or .doc'''
resume_texts, resume_names = [], []

```
# Loop over the contents of the directory containing the resumes, filtering by .pdf or .doc(x)
for resume in list(filter(lambda x: extension in x, os.listdir(PROJECT_DIR + '/CV'))):
    if extension == 'pdf':
        # Read in every resume with pdf extension in the directory
        resume_texts.append(nlp(extract_text_from_pdf(PROJECT_DIR + '/CV/' + resume)))
    elif 'doc' in extension:
        # Read in every resume with .doc or .docx extension in the directory
        resume_texts.append(nlp(extract_text_from_word(PROJECT_DIR + '/CV/' + resume)))
        
    resume_names.append(resume.split('_')[0].capitalize())
```

here it the code that i'm trying to run

Answer (score 6):

You will need a click version of minimum 8.0.0 to resolve this.
Use the command below to upgrade to latest version

`pip install --upgrade click`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and solved it this way: First, I updated Conda, running this command on Conda's own Powershell `conda update -n base -c defaults conda`
Then in the same PowerShell, running these 2 commands from Spacy's documentation: `conda install -c conda-forge spacy python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm` Source: https://spacy.io/usage

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to click v8, e.g. with `pip install 'click~=8.0'`.

Comment: I had the same error as the author, running the line you kindly posted on my CMD gave me: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 8.0 (from versions: none). I also tried pip install click 8.1.3 and had the same reply. The command pip install click reports the following: "Requirement already satisfied"... Thanks :)

Comment: What version do you get with `pip install -U click`? I think you would need python 3.7+ for this version of `click`, so if you have python 3.6, I think you'd need to try earlier versions of `typer` instead of newer versions of `click`. (The original author has python 3.8 and I think this answer should be the easiest workaround for that case.)

Comment: Thank you! Actually, what I did was to update conda from Conda's own powershell using the command     $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda. Then, I ran these 2 commands to install Spacy and the lib: conda install -c conda-forge spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm   It did work. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade the library click by running `pip install -U click`

If you are using Jupyter, reset the kernel after upgrading click.